# How to use index match when you have 2 values?

Tags: indexing, match

I have a list with 300 names codes and each of these names have more than 1 value, e.g.,

```
CODE - VALUE
300 - 1
300 - 2
300 - 3
400 - 1 
400 - 2
```

For each code, I want to return the greatest value, and after that I want to transform this greatest value into his name, e.g.,

```
CODE - VALUE - NAME
300 - 1 - alpha
300 - 2 - beta
300 - 3 - gamma
400 - 1 - theta
400 - 2 - sigma
```

So for code “300” I want to return “gamma” and for code “400” I want to return “sigma”.

Any thoughts?

Regards

Comment: do the names in the second table already exist?  Is the first table just the first two columns of the second table?

Answer (score 0):

place the following formula in F1 and the code you are looking for in E1.  This assumes your second table is located in A1:C5.   Adjust ranges to suit your data.  Avoid full column references within the aggregrate function.

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A1:A5)/((A1:A5=E1)*(B1:B5=AGGREGATE(14,6,B1:B5/(A1:A5=E1),1))),1))
```

[image: POC]